# depthimage_to_laserscan

Tags: ros, depthimage-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone tried to get the depthimage_to_laserscan to run with the gazebo kinetic plugin. I can not seem to get it to work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204010/depthimage_to_laserscan/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2015-03-01

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [slivingston](https://answers.ros.org/users/829/slivingston/) on 2015-03-02**:
Could you be more specific? E.g., what commands did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got pointcloud_to_laserscan working, not a solution but good enough.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2015-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0